# Query optimization_T- SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis

we have 14M data in a source table and wanted to know what are all the possible ways to insert data from source table to destination table without dropping indexes. Indexes are created on destination table but not on source table. In SSIS package we tried with Data flow task, Lookup and by using Execute SQL task, but there is no use and lacking in performance. So, Kindly let me now the possible ways to speedup the insertion without dropping indexes. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a necessity to not drop the indexes? In some cases its faster to drop the index, insert all the data and rebuilt the index.

Comment: If the tables are in the same database, I suggest you use INSERT/SELECT. Don't use a data flow. Why would you need to use a Lookup? To see if the record already exists?  You'll need to provide more detail: Does the target table have data? Are you trying to avoid inserting duplicates? Do you have a primary key or unique index defined in the target?

Comment: @nick- tables are on different database and the table already consists some data. In DFT, firstly we are truncating and loading data( which slow down the insertion). With lookup, it will fetch the no match record do the insertion but I don't see any improvement and we have primary key, unique index on table

Comment: @d0little- yes, by dropping indexes some other jobs may be impacted, so we are not dropping any indexes.

Comment: If you only insert data, then it depends on the tables. If you are using an identity column for primary key, then you could select and save the max identity value on the target to an SSIS variable.  Then select rows on the Source that are greater than the SSIS variable for insert. Alternatively, if you are doing a 1 to 1 sync/copy and need to track updates & deletes - then you might consider Change Data Capture (SQL Server 2016+) with 'net changes'. That syncs tables between source and target using net inserts, updates, and deletes. Both methods should "increase performance".

Comment: @Zorkolot-we don't have any identity column for primary key. But will try with change Data capture as you suggested. Thanks 

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and all this missing information - i.e. tables are on different servers, it's a daily activity. These statements are contradictory: _we are truncating and loading data_ and _With lookup, it will fetch the no match record do the insertion_. Are you truncating or merging into existing data? It sounds like you can't touch existing data so clearly you are not truncating data.

Comment: As mentioned in comments below, do not use SSIS lookup. Truncate and load into a local staging table using SSIS, then optimise merge into the target table using T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

> `let me now the possible ways to speedup the insertion without dropping indexes`

```
It really depend upon the complete set up.
What is real query like or what is table schema ?
How many indexes are there ?
Is it one time operation or  daily avg will be 14m.
```

General answer :

i) Run insert operation in downtime or during very minimum traffic hour.

ii) Use `TABLOCK` hint

```
INSERT INTO TAB1 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3
FROM TAB2
```

iii) You can think of disable/Rebuild index

```
    ALTER INDEX ALL ON sales.customers
    DISABLE;

--Insert query

    ALTER INDEX ALL ON sales.customers
    REBUILD ;
    GO
```

iv) If source server is different then you can put source data in some destination parking table which is without index.Now again another job will put from parking to destination table.

Transaction between same server will be relatively faster.

Comment: @kumarharsh- it is daily activity not one time. 14 indexes are present on the table. As per the requirement we should not drop or disable indexes which leads to an impact on some other jobs.

Comment: @kumarharsh-as you said both tables are in different servers. We are following the below steps, 1. Transfer data from source server(A table) to destination server(B table). 2. Transfer data from destination server(B table) to source server (C table).

Comment: @Geeta, you mean first you are transfer data from Source (Table A) to destination Server (Table B). Again Transfer Table B to same source Table C ? `Plz explain properly`.You should use Parking Table funnda and definetly point i) and ii)

Comment: @kumarharsh- Thank you